# How to know that my callstack is wrong?

Tags: debugging

How can I recognize that the callstack that is shown by the debugger when my program crashes may be wrong and misleading. For example when the callstack says the following frames may be missing or incorrect, what that actually means? Also what the + number after the function call in the callstack means :

kernel32!LoadLibrary + 0x100 bytes

Should this number be important to me, and is it true that if this number is big the callstack may be incorrect ?

Sorry if I am asking something trivial and obvious

Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you can trust your callstack to be correct.

However, if you re-throw exceptions explicitly instead of allowing them to bubble up the callstack naturally, the actual error can be hidden from the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

To start with the 2nd one: `kernel32!LoadLibrary + 0x100 bytes` means that the call was from the function LoadLibrary (offset: +100 bytes); appearantly there was no symbolic information exactly identifying the caller. This in itself is no reason for the callstack to be corrupted.

A call stack may be corrupted if functions overwrite values on the stack (i.e. by buffer overflow. This would likely show as '0x41445249' (if it were my name to overwrite it) as a call function. That is something outside your program memory ranges.

A way to diagnose the cause of your crash would be to set breakpoints on functions identified by the call stack. Or use your debugger to backtrace (depending on debugger & system). It is interesting to find out what arguments were included in the calls. Pointers are generally a good start (NULL pointers, uninitialized pointers). Good luck.

Comment: Isn't 0x100 actually an offset of 256 bytes?